# Driver not found - PDO - AMPPS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was using MAMP for a few months now, but today I installed AMPPS.

I am going to work with databases, but it doesn't work.
I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/functions.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/AMPPS/www/functions.php(13): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'usbw') #1 /Applications/AMPPS/www/functions.php(22): dbConn() #2 /Applications/AMPPS/www/test.php(18): imageDropdown('s') #3 {main} thrown in /Applications/AMPPS/www/functions.php on line 13
```

Code:

```
// database connection
function dbConn() {

    $username = "root";
    $password = "usbw";

    $dbh = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost; port=3306; dbname=webshop',
        $username,
        $password
    );

    return $dbh;

}

// dropdown met afbeeldingen
function imageDropdown($zoek) {

    $dbh = dbConn();

    $sth = $dbh -> prepare("

        SELECT afbeelding
        FROM Afbeelding
        WHERE afbeelding LIKE '%:zoek%'
        ORDER BY afbeelding

    ");

    $sth -> bindValue(":zoek", $zoek, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $sth -> execute();

    $result = $sth -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    print("<pre>");
    print_r($result);
    print("</pre>");

}
```

?>

(functions.php)

```
        <?php

        include "functions.php";

        imageDropdown("s");

    ?>
```

(test.php)

There is a driver missing, but how do I install it?

I'm on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user interface - PHP tab - php extension. Check if required extensions are enabled. Like pdo_mysql and pdo

Comment: pdo_pgsql.so wasn't checked. Everything else with sql and pro was checked. Now I checked pro_pgsql.so and it seems to be working now. Thanks!